How to efficiently insert or upsert a single column in PostgreSQL for optimal performance?
I'm seeking guidance on how to use PostgreSQL to update multiple rows in a specific column. I’m particularly interested in methods that offer optimal performance. Any help would be greatly appreciated
I created a ref table here DBFiddle.
My goal is to update the status column of all records to "INACTIVE". Currently, I'm working with a small table, but in a real-world scenario, I would need to apply this to approximately 10,000 records.
I attempted to use a particular method (which I'll detail below), but I was unable to get it to function correctly.
INSERT INTO questionnaires (id, status) 
VALUES (...), (...) 
ON CONFLICT UPDATE

And as an example I was trying
INSERT INTO questionnaires (id, status)
VALUES (190, 'ACTIVE'), (191, 'ACTIVE') 
ON CONFLICT (id)
   DO
     UPDATE
     SET status = EXCLUDED.status
     WHERE questionnaires.status <> EXCLUDED.status;

I consistently encounter a "not-null violation" error for the other columns. I've read online that the method I'm trying to use should be more optimized and performance-friendly, allowing me to update all records at once instead of one by one. However, I'm struggling to implement it without errors.
One approach I've considered is to first select all the relevant records, then pass all the data, along with the updates I want to make, to the insert operation. This might help me avoid the null issue.
However, I suspect there might be a more efficient way to accomplish this. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE
From code base I'm illustrating what lead to this question to let understand better my issue
This method is under a Class which does DB operation using KnexJS
  updateMulti(questionnairesData) {
    const updates = questionnairesData.map(({ id, ...input }) => ({
      id,
      ...prepareQuestionnaire(input),
    }));
    if (isEmpty(updates)) {
      return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
    return updates.map((update) =>
      this.tx(tableName)
        .returning(selectColumns)
        .where(columnsByProperties.id, update.id)
        .update(update)
        .then(head)
    );
  }

On the above method I got this feedback from a person
"This is basically one query per questionnaire. When I was looking into an alternative - update all at once I found an interesting trick: insert (id, status) values (...), (...) on conflict update Might be better or worse. Just sharing it as an idea."
The method is called in a service class as
 await questionnaires.updateMulti(
        questionnaireIds.map((id) => ({
          id,
          status: 'ACTIVE',
        }))
      );

I'm getting from another method the IDs and I need to update the status to 'ACTIVE' for all of those questionnaires.
What I need is that thew operation should handle heavy data

Why do you try to INSERT 2 new records that clearly fail because of many constraint violations, when you actually want to UPDATE these 2 records?

Because, a colleague at work suggested that to be more performant I should use a multiple insert with the onConflict to update the existing records instead of doing one by one. the reason is that need to do thousands of records in real life. The query is used in NodeJS method. However, I accept suggestions which might be more good for what I want to achieve.
I want to update status column only.

Sounds like you should be using an array or JSON to do a joined update. But if you are getting Not-Null violations then there are missing columns which you need to specify.

Yes, using multiple values() for a single insert gives you better performance. But you must have content for at least all your NOT NULL columns. That's where your INSERT fails.

I’m confused by your question/comments. Your question states that you want to update the status column of all records. If that’s what you want to do then what’s stopping you running a simple UPDATE statement? If that’s not what you want to do then please could you update your question to clarify what you do want to do, possibly with some example data to illustrate your scenarios

I'll share from base code which is JS and KnexJS to illustrate better the scenario in my question

an interesting trick This can't work because of the constraints and if it did work, it will cause a lot of extra work for the database: dead tuples for the failed inserts that have to be vacuumed later on. An UPDATE can update many records at once, you can also join other tables to find the data you want to update, etc. Your code makes it complicated, the SQL part is simple.

I think maybe better to do something like this in KnexJS
return this.tx(tableName)
.returning(selectColumns)
.whereIn('id', ids)
.update(prepareQuestionnaire(updatedData));

If you only want to update existing rows, use UPDATE:
UPDATE questionnaires
SET status = t.s
FROM (VALUES (190, 'ACTIVE'), 
             (191, 'ACTIVE')) AS t(i,s)
WHERE t.i = questionnaires.id;

